# Least costly method of combining multiple select statements to output one row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following SELECT statements in a stored procedure:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalCreditDenied
FROM   Table1
WHERE  StatusId = 8
       AND ManufacturerId = 1;

SELECT COUNT(*) AS TotalCreditApproved
FROM   Table1
WHERE  StatusId = 7
       AND ManufacturerId = 1;

SELECT SUM(CreditInvoiceAmount) AS TotalCreditPaid
FROM   Table1
WHERE  ManufacturerId = 1

SELECT SUM(ApproxCreditDue) AS OutstandingBalance
FROM   Table1
WHERE  StatusId = 3
       AND ManufacturerId = 1;

SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(day, ReturnDate, CreditInvoiceDate)) AS AverageTimeToPay
FROM   Table1
WHERE  ManufacturerId = 1
```

I am trying to find the fastest and least costly way to get these return values back as a single result set with one row. Right now, it returns 5 result sets. I can use `UNION` to get one column of all the values, but how could I get the return values in 5 columns and one row.

Additionally, is there any way to execute these queries so the database only has to be scanned once instead of 5 times?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a `SELECT ... WHERE  ManufacturerId = 1` and `CASE`

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE
               WHEN StatusId = 8
                 THEN 1
             END)                                        AS TotalCreditDenied,
       COUNT(CASE
               WHEN StatusId = 7
                 THEN 1
             END)                                        AS TotalCreditApproved,
       SUM(CreditInvoiceAmount)                          AS TotalCreditPaid,
       SUM(CASE
             WHEN StatusId = 3
               THEN ApproxCreditDue
           END)                                          AS OutstandingBalance,
       AVG(DATEDIFF(day, ReturnDate, CreditInvoiceDate)) AS AverageTimeToPay
FROM   Table1
WHERE  ManufacturerId = 1;
```

Comment: I think you need to change those COUNTS to SUMS with an ELSE 0 clause.

Comment: @TabAlleman No, default is `ELSE NULL`. And count of expression is count of non-nulls. Plus count shows intent of counting.

Comment: Note that this approach causes you to receive a warning if you have `ansi_warnings` set to `on`.

Comment: @jmc - Which can safely be ignored, so does `SELECT SUM(low) from master..spt_values`. And `concat_null_yields_null` doesn't have anything to do with it, there is no string concatenation going on.

Comment: @MartinSmith You're right, I thought there was an option regarding null behavior during aggregation, not sure what I was remembering.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to consolidate those into something like the following:

```
Select SUM(CASE StatusId WHEN 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TotalCreditDenied 
     , SUM(CASE StatusId WHEN 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as TotalCreditApproved
     , SUM(CreditInvoiceAmount) as TotalCreditPaid
     , SUM(CASE StatusId WHEN 3 THEN ApproxCreditDue ELSE 0 END) as OutstandingBalance
     , AVG(DATEDIFF(day,ReturnDate, CreditInvoiceDate)) as AverageTimeToPay  
    from Table1 where ManufacturerId = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of CASE WHEN come handy to acheive what you desire

```
SELECT  TotalCreditDenied   = COUNT(CASE WHEN StatusId = 8 THEN 1 END),
        TotalCreditApproved = COUNT(CASE WHEN StatusId = 7 THEN 1 END),
        TotalCreditPaid     = SUM(CreditInvoiceAmount),
        OutstandingBalance  = SUM(CASE WHEN StatusId = 3 THEN ApproxCreditDue END),
        AverageTimeToPay    = AVG(DATEDIFF(day,ReturnDate, CreditInvoiceDate))
FROM Table1 
WHERE ManufacturerId = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run it in a single SELECT using some CASE:

```
SELECT
   SUM(CASE WHEN StatusId = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) AS TotalCreditDenied,
   SUM(CASE WHEN StatusId = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) AS TotalCreditApproved,
   SUM(CreditInvoiceAmount) AS TotalCreditPaid,
   SUM(CASE WHEN StatusId = 3 THEN ApproxCreditDue ELSE 0 end) AS OutstandingBalance,
   AVG(DATEDIFF(DAY,ReturnDate, CreditInvoiceDate)) AS AverageTimeToPay 
FROM Table1 
WHERE ManufacturerId = 1
```